# Minizinc: Job Shop Problem, minimize taking too long

Tags: minizinc

I have a version of the Job Shop Problem where the tasks can have multiple dependency(hard constraint) and have a deadline(soft constraint).

Finding a solution where the dependency is met and there is no overlap isn't the problem, the problem is when i try to "minimize" the number of tasks that will break the deadline. When i use the "minimize" in the "solve", the running process takes more than 30 minutes and don't finish (if i use "satisfy" it ends in 20 seconds) (for 3000 tasks using Chuffed solver).

Any ideas on how to apply the soft constraint (deadline) in a reasonable time ?

the .mzn file:

```
include "disjunctive.mzn";

int: dispositiveQty;
int: taskQty;

set of int: DEVICE = 0..dispositiveQty;
set of int: TASK = 1..taskQty;

array[TASK] of int: duration;
array[TASK] of DEVICE: devTask; % device on which the task will run
array[TASK] of set of TASK: dependency; % which tasks has to be finished before the task can start
array[TASK] of int: maxDateTask; % deadline of the task

int: maxTime = sum(t in TASK)(duration[t]);

array[TASK] of var 0..maxTime: taskStart;

constraint forall(t in TASK where dependency[t] != {})
  (taskStart[t] >= max(d in dependency[t])(taskStart[d] + duration[d])); 

int: dev1 = 125;
int: dev2 = 5;
int: dev3 = 18;
int: dev5 = 2;
int: dev6 = 786;
int: dev7 = 291;
int: dev8 = 3;
int: dev9 = 226;
int: dev10 = 906;
int: dev11 = 720;
int: dev12 = 4;
int: dev13 = 36;
int: dev15 = 4;
int: dev16 = 2;
int: dev17 = 14;
int: dev18 = 42;
int: dev21 = 2;

constraint let{array[1..dev1] of var 0..maxTime: dev1Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 1],
array[1..dev1] of var int: dev1Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 1]
} in disjunctive(dev1Start, dev1Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev2] of var 0..maxTime: dev2Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 2],
array[1..dev2] of var int: dev2Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 2]
} in disjunctive(dev2Start, dev2Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev3] of var 0..maxTime: dev3Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 3],
array[1..dev3] of var int: dev3Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 3]
} in disjunctive(dev3Start, dev3Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev5] of var 0..maxTime: dev5Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 5],
array[1..dev5] of var int: dev5Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 5]
} in disjunctive(dev5Start, dev5Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev6] of var 0..maxTime: dev6Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 6],
array[1..dev6] of var int: dev6Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 6]
} in disjunctive(dev6Start, dev6Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev7] of var 0..maxTime: dev7Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 7],
array[1..dev7] of var int: dev7Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 7]
} in disjunctive(dev7Start, dev7Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev8] of var 0..maxTime: dev8Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 8],
array[1..dev8] of var int: dev8Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 8]
} in disjunctive(dev8Start, dev8Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev9] of var 0..maxTime: dev9Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 9],
array[1..dev9] of var int: dev9Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 9]
} in disjunctive(dev9Start, dev9Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev10] of var 0..maxTime: dev10Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 10],
array[1..dev10] of var int: dev10Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 10]
} in disjunctive(dev10Start, dev10Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev11] of var 0..maxTime: dev11Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 11],
array[1..dev11] of var int: dev11Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 11]
} in disjunctive(dev11Start, dev11Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev12] of var 0..maxTime: dev12Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 12],
array[1..dev12] of var int: dev12Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 12]
} in disjunctive(dev12Start, dev12Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev13] of var 0..maxTime: dev13Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 13],
array[1..dev13] of var int: dev13Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 13]
} in disjunctive(dev13Start, dev13Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev15] of var 0..maxTime: dev15Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 15],
array[1..dev15] of var int: dev15Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 15]
} in disjunctive(dev15Start, dev15Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev16] of var 0..maxTime: dev16Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 16],
array[1..dev16] of var int: dev16Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 16]
} in disjunctive(dev16Start, dev16Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev17] of var 0..maxTime: dev17Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 17],
array[1..dev17] of var int: dev17Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 17]
} in disjunctive(dev17Start, dev17Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev18] of var 0..maxTime: dev18Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 18],
array[1..dev18] of var int: dev18Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 18]
} in disjunctive(dev18Start, dev18Duration);

constraint let{array[1..dev21] of var 0..maxTime: dev21Start = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 21],
array[1..dev21] of var int: dev21Duration = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == 21]
} in disjunctive(dev21Start, dev21Duration);

var int: aboveDeadline = sum(i in TASK where maxDateTask[i] < (taskStart[i] + duration[i]))(1);

solve :: int_search([taskStart[t] | t in TASK], input_order, indomain_min, complete) satisfy;%minimize aboveDeadline;
```

the .dzn file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/94n7fqxzcai5tvf/testData.dzn?dl=0

(i can't put the .dzn file directly because it exceeds the character limit)

Comment: Can you please provide, by editing your question, the `dzn` file as well? Otherwise your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin i put the link of the dzn file

Comment: No surprise it takes forever, the `FlatZinc` file is as large as `529MB`. Would you also have a very small `dzn` file just for testing purposes?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin what solver did you use ?
I'm using Chuffed, and the size of the FlatZinc file is 3MB.
With Gecode is 296MB.

The link of the files with small data:
mzn: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b440glx46tmzxku/testSmall.mzn?dl=0
dzn: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ycay9ig8xo3trd/dataSmall.dzn?dl=0

Comment: No particular solver, I compiled the model with `mzn2fzn`.

Answer (score 3):

By introducing a new parameter `tasks`, which holds the number of tasks per device, all of the `disjunctive` constraints can be generated by a single `forall` loop. (Even better would be to move the `tasks` parameter to the data file, then the same model could be used across the different instances).

**Edit**: `tasks` can also be directly derived as `array[DEVICE] of int: tasks = [sum(t in TASK)(d == devTask[t]) | d in DEVICE];` given `DEVICE` is re-defined as `set of int: DEVICE = 1..dispositiveQty;`

Using the model below, Chuffed finds a solution to the larger instance in ~10s.

```
include "disjunctive.mzn";

int: dispositiveQty;
int: taskQty;

set of int: DEVICE = 0..dispositiveQty;
set of int: TASK = 1..taskQty;

array[TASK] of int: duration;
array[TASK] of DEVICE: devTask; % device on which the task will run
array[TASK] of set of TASK: dependency; % which tasks has to be finished before the task can start
array[TASK] of int: maxDateTask; % deadline of the task

int: maxTime = sum(t in TASK)(duration[t]);

array[TASK] of var 0..maxTime: taskStart;

constraint forall(t in TASK, d in dependency[t])
  (taskStart[t] >= taskStart[d] + duration[d]); 

array[int] of int: tasks = [125, 5, 18, 0, 2, 786, 291, 3, 226, 906, 720, 4, 36, 0, 4, 2, 14, 42, 0, 0, 2];

constraint forall(d in index_set(tasks) where tasks[d] > 0)
    (let {array[1..tasks[d]] of var int: taskStarts = [taskStart[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == d]; 
           array[1..tasks[d]] of var int: durations = [duration[i] | i in TASK where devTask[i] == d]} 
      in disjunctive(taskStarts, durations));

var int: aboveDeadline = sum(i in TASK)(bool2int(taskStart[i] + duration[i] > maxDateTask[i]));

solve :: int_search(taskStart, input_order, indomain_min, complete)
minimize aboveDeadline;

output ["aboveDeadline=\(aboveDeadline)"];
```

Comment: In the ~10s it returns an itermediate solution, not the optimal solution.
This was already happening, the running process still keep running for more than 30 minutes

Comment: Tried a few things, but no real performance improvement. Ordering the tasks by number of dependencies (effectively putting the leading tasks first), Chuffed finds a solution faster, but no drastical improvement. Like `solve :: int_search([taskStart[i] | i in arg_sort([card(dependency[i]) | i in TASK])], input_order, indomain_min, complete)`. Investigating whether there are equal jobs (same sequence of tasks on same devices and with same duration) on the large instance shows there are only few - explicit ordering of these jobs would not bring much.

Comment: Also tried a disjunctive MIP-model for job shop scheduling, however, on the large instance no solution is found within 10 minutes (using the OSICBC solver). For a computational analysis of different models see [http://tidel.mie.utoronto.ca/pubs/JSP_CandOR_2016.pdf](http://tidel.mie.utoronto.ca/pubs/JSP_CandOR_2016.pdf).